# Does collect return a list snapshot if run on a parallel stream?

Tags: kotlin, java-8, java-stream

I have a unit test that started to fail on Circle CI **only**. It fails on the last line in this (Kotlin) example:

```
generator.generateNames(50) // returns List<String>
.parallelStream()
.map { name ->
    val playerId = "${name.firstName.toLowerCase()}"
    Player(playerId = playerId)
}.collect(Collectors.toList()).last()
```

throwing: `Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

It works always on my local machine or on Circle CI if I do not use a parallel stream. My theory is that the `collect` call returns a List snapshot (it actually doesn't block until the List is completely filled) and that CI doesn't have enough CPU to collect a single element in other threads?

However, my stream is ordered and so is the Collector right? Is this even collecting in parallel?

Comment: Does the returned list definitely contain an element? `.last()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` if it is empty

Comment: Yes. Like I said running the code unchanged on my dev machine always work. On CI it works if I turn the parallel stream into a sequential one.

Comment: Not very sure of what Kotlin does, but if making things sequential seems to be the only solution currently. Then I would suggest trying to `collect(Collectors.toList())` as `Player` list and break the part of fetching the last into two steps. Something like this in [tag:java] : `List<Player> playerList = generator.generateNames(50) // returns List<String>
.parallelStream()
.map(name ->
    new Player(name.getFirstName.toLowerCase())
}.collect(Collectors.toList()); Player lastplayer = playerList.get(playerList.size()-1);` .. note that this shouldn't work either on Circle CI for your code.

Comment: I don’t understand, in which regard “Circle CI” is relevant in this operation at all. The only thing that doesn’t look standard Java or trivial operation, is `generator.generateNames(50)`. If this method returns one of the standard `List` implementations, there should be no problem. But perhaps, it returns some kind of lazy list implementation that is not thread safe?

Comment: What flavour and version of a JDK are you using on both machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception you are getting probably has a message in it, and not just the name of the exception.  That message is likely telling you the error.  For example, the last part of your code calls the Kotlin extension function `last()` which in the implementation:

```
public fun <T> List<T>.last(): T {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw NoSuchElementException("List is empty.")
    return this[lastIndex]
}
```

So if you are seeing "List is empty" message in the stack trace for `java.util.NoSuchElementException` then that is the cause.

Also, if you share the stack trace you can actually see what is throwing the exception. But looking at your code this is the only likely candidate.

The question then is, "why is the final list empty?!" ... is `generateNames(50)` working differently in this environment?  The problem is not with `collect(Collectors.toList())` which provides a synchronous result.

Comment: After some investigation, it turned out that running a parallel stream exhausted a JedisPool. I excluded that line above because I thought it would be not relevant. It was a bit unfortunate that the exhausted pool also came back with a `NoSuchElementException`. That got me to the wrong track. But basically you answered my question: when `collect(Collectors.toList())` returns, the `List` is always fully populated - also when using parallel streams.